# Typescript: unexpected token when using "as HTMLElement" type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to Typescript. I am getting the following error when using the HTMLElement type within a `forEach` loop:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/mount.jsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/me/projects/mathllc/app/javascript/mount.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (7:34)

   5 |     const mountPoints = document.querySelectorAll('[data-react-component]')
   6 |     mountPoints.forEach((mountPoint) => {
>  7 |       const dataset = (mountPoint as HTMLElement).dataset
     |                                   ^
   8 |       const componentName = dataset['reactComponent']
   9 |       const Component = components[componentName]
  10 |       if (Component) {
```

I am following this tutorial by @Ryan Bigg : https://egghead.io/blog/rails-graphql-typescript-react-apollo

My code is here:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
export default function mount(components = {}) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const mountPoints = document.querySelectorAll('[data-react-component]')
    mountPoints.forEach((mountPoint) => {
      const dataset = (mountPoint as HTMLElement).dataset
      const componentName = dataset['reactComponent']
      const Component = components[componentName]
      if (Component) {
        const props = JSON.parse(dataset['props'])
        ReactDOM.render(<Component {...props} />, mountPoint)
      } else {
        console.log(
          'WARNING: No component found for: ',
          dataset.reactComponent,
          components,
        )
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does your code have `import * as React from "react";`?  If not, it could be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error - `ERROR in ./app/javascript/mount.jsx`) - it appears that you are not using a `.tsx` file and the keyword `as` is not valid Javascript so you either should remove the `as HTMLElement` because Javascript does not care about types or change the filename to `mount.tsx` - if you are using a Typescript compiler in your build chain.